# Synchronizing data

Tags: qfield

Av been using QField to collect some data which I collected and also pushed changes once av synchronized it tells me successfully downloaded, though am not able to see the data I picked on the screen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is av?.....